# Get specific values from randomized multidimensional array with url key

Tags: php, arrays, url, random, key

I don't quit get how to echo the two items (separately) from a specific key number. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to keep the current random function, but be able to get a specific set of values from the array through a url like `index.php?key=3` when needed – for let's say when a visitor randomizes "Third rzU_fLcxIN0" and would like to share this with someone, who then proceeds to view the url `index.php?key=3` with the corresponding values, and is able to continue by randomizing new values with the button.

Maybe I'm asking a lot, but it feels like this shouldn't be to complicated to put together once one understands what parts to use (and how). I'm new to this so all help and pointers on how to solve something like this are useful to me!

**Update**
I'll try to explain the random vs. non random question a bit better. The standard behavior will be to display random content to visitors, but with the possibility for visitors to share specific posts with others.
Imagine the following steps as as "Visitor" visits the site;

1. Visitor enters site and clicks button to randomize new content on each click.
2. Visitor finds something interesting from the randomized content and wants to share it with "*Friend*".
3. Visitor copy the share-url `index.php?key=3` from a field on the site ([Example](http://assets.koken.me/help/soundcloud_share.png)).
4. "*Friend*" enters the site via the shared url, and the content from `key=3` is displayed.
5. "*Friend*" likes the site and wants to see more content, so he clicks the randomize button.
6. "*Friend*" continues to view random content, despite having arrived from a content specific url.

**index.php**

```
<a class="randomizerButton" data-href="data.php">Randomize</a>
<hr>
<div id="results">
<?php include('data.php'); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.randomizerButton').click(function(){
            scriptUrl = $(this).attr('data-href');
            $.post(scriptUrl, function(response){
                $('#results').html(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php

$var = array(  
    //1,2,3,4... etc. are unique IDs
    1 => array("First", "0wLljngvrpw"),   
    2 => array("Second", "TINASKjjNfw"),  
    3 => array("Third", "rzU_fLcxIN0"),
    4 => array("Fourth", "aZZ8UnCTVJA"),
);  
$finalVar = $var[array_rand($var)];  
echo $finalVar[0].'<br/>'.$finalVar[1];

echo ('<hr>');

// I've started out with things like the one below but I don't know how to output the values from a multidimensional array,
// Didn't manage to find a helpful resource on the problem, mainly since I don't know if this is the correct way to approach this.

$key='2';
echo $var[$key]; //outputs Array, need to go one level deeper I guess?


// Any pointers on how to load this specific value while maintaining the random button function as well, I'd be very grateful.

// $_GET["key"]...?
    // loop array...?

?>
```

Comment: you want to specify the `$key` but you want it random? that's odd. by the way to access it just use `$var[$key][0]` and `$var[$key][1]`

Comment: try $var[$key][0] that's how you access the nested arrays, for your random -vs- non random I don't understand what you want?  You can do this $var[$_GET['key']][$_GET['index']] etc...  but you might want to check with isset( $var[$_GET['key']] ) first for error checking

Comment: @Ghost Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I've updated the description to hopefully make sense of the random/non random situation if you'd like to take a look at it.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Great, that worked fine for accessing the nested arrays – as for the random vs. non random business, I've updated the original question so that it hopefully makes more sense now if you'd like to take a crack at it or tell me if it's even a sane approach to attempt.

Comment: well if you want that just substitute/assign `$_GET['key']` with `$key`, should be fairly straightforward, if the page is accessed thru `GET` they feed it thru a key, else feed it randomly

Comment: @Ghost Yeah that works when using both `$finalVar = $var[array_rand($var)];` and `$_GET['key'];`, but to unify them and display only one output, wouldn't I have to replace the array_rand value with my key-value somehow? Maybe I'm just tired but I can't make any sensible merger of the two.

Comment: that's it, if I understand your update, you just need to check for the proper get variable.  if( isset( $_GET['key'] ) ) - fixed item ( else ) random item

Comment: just write a condition, if get is provided, then use that to access `$var`, if not, then use the randomized way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to better explain my comment, for the fixed vs random, this is a logical condition and for that we use an if statement.

Consider you have the url `index.php?key=3`, we just check for that in the `$_GET`

```
if( isset( $_GET['key'] ) && isset( $var[$_GET['key']] ) ){
   $finalVar = $var[$_GET['key']];
} else {
   $finalVar = $var[array_rand($var)];
}
```

when someone randomize the input just do a

```
header('location: index.php');
exit();
```

to clear the url.  Or from Javascript

```
window.location.href = 'index.php';
```

That will fail on the `if` and execute in the `else` part of the condition, which will access the array using a random key, otherwise if the `key` is in the url query and in the array `$var` they will get that item.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks for taking time to explain, helped me a lot.